# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS to later version

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, python

Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

I want to upgrade to newer Ubuntu and newer OpenSSH, but it is failing. Any ideas how to get past this?

do-release-upgrade

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 11, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN13debListParser12ParseDependsEPKcS1_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_RjRKbSB_SB_RKS7_ version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN13debListParser12ParseDependsEPKcS1_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_RjRKbSB_SB_RKS7_ version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 11, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN13debListParser12ParseDependsEPKcS1_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_RjRKbSB_SB_RKS7_ version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
```

sudo apt update

```
Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Fetched 163 kB in 0s (618 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
423 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

sudo apt upgrade

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub-pc : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02-2ubuntu8.21) but 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18 is installed
 grub-pc-bin : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02-2ubuntu8.21) but 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18 is installed
 grub2-common : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02-2ubuntu8.21) but 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18 is installed
 libpython2.7-stdlib : Depends: libreadline7 (>= 7.0~beta) but it is not installed
 libpython3.6-stdlib : Depends: libreadline7 (>= 7.0~beta) but it is not installed
 python-apt : Depends: libapt-inst2.0 (>= 1.6.5~) but 1.2.27 is installed
              Depends: libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.6.5~) but 1.2.27 is installed
 python3-apt : Depends: libapt-inst2.0 (>= 1.6.5~) but 1.2.27 is installed
               Depends: libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.6.5~) but 1.2.27 is installed
 python3-cryptography : Depends: python3-asn1crypto (>= 0.21.0~) but it is not installed
                        Depends: python3-idna (>= 2.1) but 2.0-3 is installed
 python3-gdbm : Depends: libgdbm5 (>= 1.14) but it is not installed
 python3-newt : Depends: libnewt0.52 (= 0.52.20-1ubuntu1) but 0.52.18-1ubuntu2 is installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.2) but 237-3ubuntu10.44 is installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu21.2) but 237-3ubuntu10.44 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

sudu apt-get -f install

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: libgdbm.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: libgdbm.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, please install the python3-gdbm package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdbm'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN13debListParser12ParseDependsEPKcS1_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_RjRKbSB_SB_RKS7_ version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: libgdbm.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: libgdbm.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, please install the python3-gdbm package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdbm'
```

sudu apt list --upgradable

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: libgdbm.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: libgdbm.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, please install the python3-gdbm package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdbm'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN13debListParser12ParseDependsEPKcS1_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_RjRKbSB_SB_RKS7_ version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: libgdbm.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: libgdbm.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, please install the python3-gdbm package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdbm'
```

Comment: You cannot upgrade 16.04 directly to 20.04. You first need to reach 18.04 and then 20.04. Amid this, you'll definitely lose Unity as 18.04 uses GNOME.

Comment: Those are 18.04 (Bionic) sources, so perhaps you have already done a partial upgrade. To repair may be possible, but will be tedious and lengthy as you chase down every error.  To backups your data and clean-install 20.04 is much faster and easier, but less of a learning challenge.

Comment: It is not clear to me at all where you are, you say 16.04.5 but I see *bionic* sources???  You need to fully-upgrade first on *xenial* ie. to 16.04.7 before upgrade should be performed? but that won't result in *bionic* as you've shown them. The python errors imply to me you've changed your python, or attempted to upgrade Ubuntu as if it's Debian (ie. amended sources) which can create python problems as *Ubuntu != Debian* (upgrade tools add a strict order to avoid python issues, plus other things..)   I see out-dated xenial packages in your messages so `do-release-upgrade` shouldn't be run yet

Comment: Thanks. I have already installed new 18/20 versions, so I will probably give up this. It was originally older v13 upgraded to v14 and later v16. The only thing I really added to this machine is ProFtpd as I test different SFTP servers. I would prefer to keep it as ProFtpd setup was lengthy. I saved the conf files now so hopefully able to re-use those on other machine. ProFtpd install:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install proftpd
I have done these to upgrade in the past:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
do-release-upgrade

but now it seems stuck in dependency bad "loop"

Comment: 18/20 version?  Ubuntu has since 2016 referred to *snap* only systems using the *year* format, to distinguish them from the *year.month* format (eg. 18.04) used by *deb* based systems.  They are different products , so no 16.04 system should be upgraded to Ubuntu Core 18/Ubuntu Core 20.  v13? v14?  Ubuntu only started using the *yy* format in 2016 so no such releases ever existed (the *yy.mm* format releases occur at least twice per year [more if you count re-spins so *yy* makes no sense for those product).  Please be precise in your questions for meaningful help.

Comment: Sorry if unclear. With 18/20, I meant two different servers with 18.04 and 20.04. I now also have other 22.04 installation as well. All working fine now for my basic usage. Thanks all.